# Error installing PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am now trying to run PyQt. I am still getting the following error
when I do the following:

```
root@localhost:/home/abhowmik/app/imgSeek-0.8.6# cd Py*
root@localhost:/home/abhowmik/app/imgSeek-0.8.6/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.8.4# python configure.py --verbose
Determining the layout of your Qt installation...
/usr/share/qt3//bin/qmake -o qtdirs.mk qtdirs.pro
make -f qtdirs.mk
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -O2 -D_REENTRANT  -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_SHARED -DQT_TABLET_SUPPORT -I/usr/share/qt3/mkspecs/default -I. -I/usr/include/qt3 -o qtdirs.o qtdirs.cpp
qtdirs.cpp:1:17: fatal error: QFile: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [qtdirs.o] Error 1
Error: Failed to determine the layout of your Qt installation. Try again using
the --verbose flag to see more detail about the problem.
root@localhost:/home/abhowmik/app/imgSeek-0.8.6/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.8.4# ^C
root@localhost:/home/abhowmik/app/imgSeek-0.8.6/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.8.4#
```

Can someone help me how to fix the problem?

Comment: I don't think importing is the problem you're having here...

Comment: if you are trying to install Qt, post details about it, OS, python version... and why are you doing a, b or c way.

Comment: Almost all systems come with a py-qt package. You probably want to install that.

Answer (score 10):

Problem is that configure.py is trying to use qmake from qt3. Try this:

```
python configure.py --qmake /usr/bin/qmake-qt4
```

(You might have qmake-qt4 somwhere else than /usr/bin so check that first )

Answer (score 4):

Try this,
http://samos-it.com/install-pyqt-in-a-virtualenv-with-pip/

Install the development headers (Ubuntu 12.04):

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

Then try again

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly modified answer of @Flyte which worked for me on CentOS 6.5

- activate your virtualenv(optional in case you want to install in virtualenv)
- wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/sip-4.15.4/sip-4.15.4.zip(your corresponding version)
- unzip sip-4.15.4.zip
- cd sip-4.15.4
- python configure.py --incdir=/opt/include/python2.7(path where python is located)
- make and make install this completes the installation of SIP one of the prerequsite
  -Then to install PyQt4
- wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10.3/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.3.tar.gz
- tar zxvf PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.3.tar.gz
- cd PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.3
- python2.7 configure.py -k --qmake /usr/bin/qmake-qt4
- make and finally make install

this worked for me hope it helps you also. also make sure you have proper version of qt installed usually need to use qt version>4.7

Answer (score 0):

Try PIP, the python package manager:

```
pip3 install pyqt5
```